# reachabilityWithHostname return YES only once

Tags: ios, reachability

I downloaded the projet Reachability on github : https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

i Have the same behavior on ios7 and ios8 (all devices on simulator).

After launching simulator with the wifi Turn ON on the computer i obtain that.
The reachabilityWithHostname return Yes and indicate that google is reachable and it is ok.

[image]

But When i turn Off the wifi on my computer the reachabilityWithHostname indicates that google is not reachable what is normal But When again i turn the wifi ON i'm not able to have reachabilityWithHostname work it indicates that Google is not reachable.
The same thing append when i launch the simulator with the wifi first turn off on my computer, the reachabilityWithHostname always indicate that google is not reachable and stay thus

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it's very hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a well known bug of simulators in xCode 6.

Try the same on your device in debug mode. It should work correctly as in case of mine.

Also I recommend to use the [original version of Reachability from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).